# Implement addActionListener() method on a custom ComboBoxEditor

Tags: java, swing, action, actionlistener, jtextarea

Good day everyone, below is the code of my custom `JComboBox` editor:

```
public class BoxEditor  implements ComboBoxEditor{

    private JTextArea editor ;

    public BoxEditor() {
        editor = new JTextArea();
        editor.setSize(360,55);
        editor.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        editor.setLineWrap(true);
        editor.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) { 
        System.out.println("addActionListener BoxEditor " + l.toString());  
    }

    @Override
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l ) {}

    @Override
    public Component getEditorComponent(){ 
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAll() {}

    @Override
    public Object getItem() { 
        System.out.println("getItem from BoxEditor : " + editor.getText());
        return editor.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void setItem(Object item) { 
        if (item != null) { 
            System.out.println("setting item to BoxEditor item is :" + item.toString() );  
            editor.setText(item.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using a `JTextArea` as editor component, but the problem is that I don't have `addActionListener()` method and as result I can't add `JComboBox` listener to my ComboBoxEditor. And when I'm using my editor no action is dispathed to the combo box.

The reason why I'm using `JTextArea` is because I need things like WrapStyleWord, LineWrap and other features which are not provided with `JTextField`.

I see that `addActionListener()` implementation is using [EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) so I've tried to do something like in example but seems that example can't produce full working issue.

The question is: **How i can i add addActionListener method  to component that don't have it?**

Or where can I find an explanation about how using `EventListener` or `AWTEventMutlicaster` for my case?

Seems that i can't explain well what i need, i know how to add ActionListener to component , i don't know how to implement method addActionListener it self.
(for example if JComboBox don't have method addActionListener and you need to add ActionListener to it).

Answer (score 0):

below sample code for jcombobox and action performed

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Combo  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();

        String[] list = { "1", "2", "3"};

        final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(list);
        panel.add(cb);
        cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(cb.getSelectedItem());
            }
        });


        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

good luck

Comment: i am interesting in implemeting addActionListener method it self 
but thanks for try to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
JComboBox date1 = new JComboBox (date);
date1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Change");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [BasicComboboxEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicComboBoxEditor.html) class is the default editor for editable combo boxes and it's implemented as a [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html). If you take a look to its implementation you'll see something like this:

```
public class BasicComboBoxEditor implements ComboBoxEditor,FocusListener {
    protected JTextField editor;

    ...

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        editor.addActionListener(l);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        editor.removeActionListener(l);
    }
}
```

It means the [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) is just forwarded to the editor. In your case the problem is [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) doesn't have methods to add/remove action listeners so you can't simply do `editor.addActionListener(l)`. But you can use an [EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) as follows:

```
class BoxEditor implements ComboBoxEditor {  
    private final EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();
    ...

    @Override
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l ) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, l);
    }
}
```

In any case as far as I know the reason of setting an action listener to the editor is allow the [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) to be notified when the edtion is finished (by pressing `Enter` key) which is possible if the editor is a `JTextField` but it doesn't make sense if the editor is a `JTextArea`. Maybe this is the reason why you stated this:

> I see that `addActionListener` implementation is using
>   `EventListenerList` i try do something like in example but seems that
>   example can't produce full working issue.

Keeping this in mind you'll need to provide a way to notify the combo box the edition is finished. For instance something like this:

```
class BoxEditor implements ComboBoxEditor {

    private final JTextArea editor ;
    private final EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    public BoxEditor() {            
        editor = new JTextArea();
        editor.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        editor.setLineWrap(true);
        editor.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
        // When CTRL + ENTER is pressed the stopEditing action is fired
        editor.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "stopEditing");
        editor.getActionMap().put("stopEditing", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(editor, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "stopEditing");
                fireActionEvent(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void fireActionEvent(ActionEvent evt){
        for(ActionListener al : listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class)){
            al.actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l ) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, l);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats something i need ,thank you.But can you tell me please how can i make action for PopUp menu showing ? 
I mean if using JTextField for editor component popup showing. 
And one more questiong pls , what usefull information get the last string parametr in ActionEvent constructor (specify a command) can i use it show popup ? something like  - new ActionEven(editor,ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,"showComoboBoxPopUp"); ?

Comment: You're welcome! :) The last string parameter is the action command and it can be obtained later by calling `actionEvent.getActionCommand()` method. You can use key-binding (this is the name of the process I've implemented to fire the `ActionEvent`) to bring up a `JPopupMenu`, there's nothing wrong on doing so, but this is tipically done by implementing a `MouseListener` as described in this section: [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup). Anyway feel free to implement both methods if you wish :) @user1722669

Comment: @dic19 puedes ver esta pregunta por favor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037906/using-the-comboboxeditor-interface-with-custom-jcomponent-and-allow-edit-and-d